# Continuity and Lebesgue measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure

Is $f(x) = m\left(B(0,|x|) \cap A\right)$ continuous if $A\subset \mathbb R^n$ is a measurable set? If not continuous, does it at least have the intermediate value property? My guess would be that I would either need to apply the lemma of Borel-Cantelli or approximate A by an open set $A \subset O_\epsilon$ of measure $\epsilon+m(A)>  m(O_\epsilon)$  but I do not see how. Thank you.

Comment: How big could $f(y) - f(x)$ be if $|y|>|x|?$ Certainly no larger than the volume of the space between the spheres of these radii.

Comment: In fact, it's Lipschitz continuous by an elementary argument (such as @zhw indicated). More interesting is finding a geometric property on the local structure of $A$ at a point $y \in {\mathbb R}^{n}$ that is necessary (or sufficient; or both necessary and sufficient) for the existence of a finite derivative of $f$ at $y.$

Comment: It occurs to me that including *finite* is kind of silly, since all the various difference quotients (directional, etc.) are bounded --- not only bounded at each point, but even locally bounded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. By Lebesgue density theorem
$$
\lim_{\delta\to0}\frac{m(B(0,|x|)\cap A\cap B(x,\delta))}{m(B(x,\delta))}\leqslant 1
$$
So given $\epsilon>0$, let $m(B(x,\delta))<\epsilon$
$$
|f(x+\delta)-f(x)|\leqslant m(B(x,\delta))<\epsilon
$$